# how to make  key event wxpython  in textctrl?

Tags: event-handling, wxpython, keycode, textctrl

here is my code

python 2.7 & wxpython 2.8

http://pastie.org/4248326

these 3 textctrl, at the chat_c(textctrl)

i want to make chat_c and text_c like a chatting room

input is chat_c output is text_c

that is why i use

```
def OnReturnDown(self,e):

    key = e.GetKeyCode()
    self.text_c.SetValue(key) #for check out but doesn't work
    if key == wx.WXK_RETURN:
        self.text_c.SetValue(self.chat_c.GetValue()) 

 #key bind
    self.chat_c.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.OnReturnDown)
```

this is error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\workspace\wx_python_test\main_chat_client.py", line 239, in OnReturnDown
    self.text_c.SetValue(key) #for check out but doesn't work
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\_controls.py", line 1754, in SetValue
    return _controls_.TextCtrl_SetValue(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: String or Unicode type required
```

what is that? Unicode type required???

maybe change the style of textctrl?

how can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

e.GetKeyCode() returns an int. You don't pass an int to a text control. A text control only takes a string or a unicode string. So you'll need to cast the int into a string or do something else. Here's how to cast it:

```
key = str( e.GetKeyCode() )
```

Comment: What happens? Can you provide a small runnable example?